# GPS antenna type

Tags: antenna, gps

i want to interface a gps module and an antenna.
I found [this kind of antenna (example)](http://www.tme.eu/en/details/org9802-150/gps-antennas/origingps/)
It does not mention its type.

Is this an active or a passive antenna?
How to be able to know by myself without the need of asking here?

Comment: If you have an active antenna, you would need to provide power somehow. Here you have only a wire for the signal and a shield around it.

Comment: @Botnic many active antennas (that is antennas with built-in amplification) are powered up the same coax that carries the signal. Carrying RF and DC power on the same cable is not an issue.

Comment: How is this possible with only 2 wires Peter? Or there are four in the same cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data sheet says: -

> ORG9802 is a miniature antenna assembly, comprising four components:
>
> 1. Ceramic patch antenna element
> 2. Adaptor PCB
> 3. Coaxial cable (option)
> 4. Connector (option)

Everything above is passive

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your "How is this possible" question: The RF signal and DC power are both on the center conductor of the cable.  At the receiver the RF is blocked from the receiver's power input with a choke, and the DC power is blocked from the signal input with a capacitor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is so cool they do it with only two cables.